# Como ejecutar código si la condición existe en mi df ( If, else)? Rstudio

Tags: r, condiciones, rstudio

Vuelvo a recurrir a la comunidad para continuar aprendiendo, mi tema es el siguiente:
Tengo un `df` que contiene varias columnas que son siempre las mismas y lo que cambia son las filas.

Necesito hacer un condicional para después ejecutar el código que me interesa, el `L5MUP14` es mi `df` en el cual quiero comprobar si en esa columna `Estrato` tengo el valor de `8`, si eso es afirmativo entonces hago el codigo que tengo armado.
Sino encuentra el numero 8, entonces no se muestre nada.
`Ribiera` es el otro `df` en donde tengo mis métricas para realizar cálculos

```
if_else (L5MUP14$Estrato==8) { # Mi df es el L5MUP14  
  rib= ribiera%>%
    group_by(Canton, Rodal)%>%
    filter(LOTE==5, MUP==14, Canton==1)%>%    
    ungroup(Canton, Rodal)
} else {
   "No hay"
}
```

He probado con `exist` pero tampoco logro hacerlo. Alguna ayuda o sugerencia?

Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if_else()` es una función vectorial que requiere que le indiques el valor en caso que el resultado sea verdadero o falso. Pero en tu caso, solo vas a evaluar una condición escalar o única, que cierto valor exista en la columna, para lo cual el `if()` tradicional es lo que hay que usar:

```
if(any(L5MUP14$Estrato==8)) { # Mi df es el L5MUP14  
  rib= ribiera%>%
    group_by(Canton, Rodal)%>%
    filter(LOTE==5, MUP==14, Canton==1)%>%    
    ungroup(Canton, Rodal)
} else {
   "No hay"
}
```

`any(L5MUP14$Estrato==8)` retornará `TRUE` si al menos hay un valor que cumpla con la condición.

Comment: Hola Patricio, es lo que buscaba, en el caso que quiera hacer una condición dentro del código, seria posible? Es decir, agrupar, filtrar y luego aplicar un if else any. Gracias un saludo

Comment: No sé si es lo que preguntas pero el `any(Estrato==8)` lo puedes usar dentro del `filter()` lo que si, si no se da esta condición, directamente no te va a traer ninguna filas.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!